# Online shop product versioning

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

Below you can see the part of my database which is responsible for storing orders.

[image: database schema]
**Short explanation**

- A user can have many orders
- A user may only have zero or one order per day (user_id + year + month + day -> unique)
- A product has a price but each user can have a special price for each product
- A product may have a container (a beer crate for example)

**Problem**

- Obviously if the product changes, previously made orders will also change (which could for example affect the price of already sold products)

**Possible solutions**

- Copy all of the products columns and save it within `order_items` but I would then need to copy all columns of `containers` too. And as products only change every now and then I think it's overhead to save the current products state with each order.
- Implement some kind of versioning for `products` and `containers`.
  Every `order_item` would then reference the current state of the
  product.

**Conclusion**

The second solution seems like the one to use, however I am pretty much stuck with this attempt as I cannot find a way that would work with in my case. I would also need versioning for my `containers` then and it still needs to be compatible with `product_user`'s special prices.

Please consider that `containers` might have additional columns in the future!

Hopefully there is some database expert out there who can help me..

**The solutions mentioned are the only two I could think of, feel free to suggest a totally different approach!**

P.S. I am using Laravel 5.3 in my project and therefor all of the associated database naming conventions.

Comment: "I think it's overhead to save the current products state with each order." It's cheap overhead, and saves you a lot of complexities.

Comment: As @ceejayoz says: save the state. It's the only reliable way to access/retrieve a snapshot of an invoice or order at the time it was made.

Comment: use a table to keep track of the product changes. all queries to sales must consider getting the appropiate product name/price from that table.

Comment: Seems legit. I guess I should save all the `container`'s information into `order_items` too?

Comment: Would something like this work for your case? https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable

Comment: Do (or will) your containers ever carry a discount?

Comment: @Samsquanch actually I found this package myself a few days ago and it look promising but I think ceejayoz is absolutely right: the additional complexity wouldn't be worth the small reduction of overhead..

Comment: @RossWilson no definetly not. The containers are reusable, so it's just to keep track how many containers a customer has at the moment.